# Efficiency of declaring DOM element variable globally

Tags: javascript, dom, scope

I'm wondering what is the best practice when it comes to declaring variables globally or not: if I have a `var foo = document.getElementById('bar')` and `foo` is only used inside a function that is called more than one time, is it best that `foo` be declared inside or outside the function (performance wise)?

If `foo` is declared inside the function, does that mean that the program has to search for that element in the DOM tree every time the function runs? If so, why isn't it better to declare `foo` outside of the function?

Comment: If you only use the `foo` var inside one function, there is no need to declare it global

Comment: I would declare it inside the function. Unless it is something like a large static list of values, or something immutable, I would stay away from trying to store it globally, it's usually best to limit scope when possible.

Comment: Can you please post your simplified code on this? As it depends

Comment: Yes, `foo` will be searched each time the function is called.

Comment: Note that if DOM is updated dynamically, using a global variable verses a function-local one could behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `foo` inside function it will be better to use it locally .Because this saves you and others from confusion . And It will be more readable.If You declare it globally then there will always a chance of misuse of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Global Declarations are to be avoided**

As a Developer your job is to limit the amount of variables available in the global scope as much as possible. *Why?* There are a few reasons and they're all good reasons.

- Readability and Intuitiveness

Other Developers should not have to hunt through the Global Scope to find what they need. Typically best practice is to store a singular Object(*singleton*). It's implied that within that Object the properties and child objects should be organized(much like a file system) making it easy to intuitively determine where certain functions and properties are located.

- Maintainability

Even if other Developers don't come in you're going to need to maintain this product to some degree typically. If that's the case separating your logic out in the Global Scope is going to be difficult if, 6 months from now, you need to make some alterations to a section only to have something, somewhere else break.

- Browser Support

Less likely but not less important, Browsers add features all the time and there are several specs setup for a multitude of features that are either being proposed, tested, or slated to be implemented. If any of your Global Declarations conflict with them you're going to have a hard time reconnecting everything after having to change your code.

**So What Should You Do?**

You should create a singleton Object, or as few objects as possible, located in Global Scope, and then build the functions and features that you need by extending that singular object. This is called Scoping and it's a very important part of development.

For the case that you gave for instance instead of writing

```
var  foo = document.getElementById('bar');

function a() {
 // do Something with foo;
}

function b() {
  // do Something with foo;
}
a();
b();
```

You would be better off writing

```
let MyApp = {
a: function() {
  //do Something with this.foo;
},
b: function() {
  //do something with this.foo;
}
}
myApp.foo = document.getElementById('bar')
myApp.a();
myApp.b();
```